# i got error when creating table with some foreign key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

i got error when creating table with some foreign key in MySQL, here is my script :

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_mt_kuliah (

KD_AUTO INT (4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
NIM INT (10) NOT NULL,
KD_MATA_KULIAH INT (4) NOT NULL,
RUANG VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL,
KD_DOSEN INT (4) NOT NULL,
JAM TIME NOT NULL,
HARI DATE NOT NULL,
TH_AJARAN YEAR NOT NULL,
SMESTER INT (2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY KD_AUTO,
FOREIGN KEY FK_MATKUL(KD_MATA_KULIAH) REFERENCES mt_kuliah (KD_MATA_KULIAH),
FOREIGN KEY FK_MHS(NIM) REFERENCES tbl_mahasiswa (NIM),
FOREIGN KEY FK_DOSEN(KD_DOSEN) REFERENCES tbl_dosen (KD_DOSEN)

);
```

and here is the error :

```
Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
foreign KEY FK_MATKUL(KD_MATA_KULIAH) references mt_kuliah (KD_MATA_KULIAH),
' at line 12
```

Comment: And when you googled your error message or 'more foreign key error information' with & without your particular names & SQL/DBMS? Please also read & act on [mcve]. This is a faq.

Comment: Please check that all the conditions required as defined here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html are met and if that doesn't help add the referenced tables to your question (including the db engine and collation).

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help you.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_mt_kuliah (
    KD_AUTO INT (4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    NIM INT (10) NOT NULL,
    KD_MATA_KULIAH INT (4) NOT NULL,
    RUANG VARCHAR (4) NOT NULL,
    KD_DOSEN INT (4) NOT NULL,
    JAM TIME NOT NULL,
    HARI DATE NOT NULL,
    TH_AJARAN YEAR NOT NULL,
    SMESTER INT (2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (KD_AUTO),
    CONSTRAINT FK_MATKUL FOREIGN KEY (KD_MATA_KULIAH) REFERENCES mt_kuliah (KD_MATA_KULIAH),
    CONSTRAINT FK_MHS FOREIGN KEY (NIM) REFERENCES tbl_mahasiswa (NIM),
    CONSTRAINT FK_DOSEN FOREIGN KEY (KD_DOSEN) REFERENCES tbl_dosen (KD_DOSEN)
 );
```

Comment: <e>Query: CREATE TABLE tbl_mt_kuliah ( KD_AUTO INT (4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, NIM INT (10) NOT NULL, KD_MATA_KULIAH INT (4) NOT NULL, RU...

Error Code: 1005
Can't create table `mercubuana`.`tbl_mt_kuliah` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: Please Check  the foreign key column and the referencing column are of the same type or length.